# How can I get the full URL in PHP, not just part of it?

Tags: php

This is my current URL structure
http://wp.raddyx.in/consultant-dietitians/staff-single/#Fiona%20Brown

I am using `echo $url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

However it displays `/consultant-dietitians/staff-single/` only, where I want to fetch the full URL.

Comment: This sounds like an XY-problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem - Please tell us about X, not Y.

Answer (score 3):

Use `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]` to get the host name `wp.raddyx.in`

Use `$_SERVER["HTTPS"]` to check for http vs https.

You might need `$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]` too and some other misc things that can appear in a URL (like `PHP_AUTH_USER`)

You can not get the hash part of the URL (`#Fiona%20Brown`) since hashes are client-side only. They are not sent to the server.

Relevant manual page: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Missing `#Fiona%20Brown`

Comment: Thanks, but what I am looking for is the url containing the #string i.e http://wp.raddyx.in/consultant-dietitians/staff-single/#Fiona%20Brown, currently I am getting up to http://wp.raddyx.in/consultant-dietitians/staff-single/ see the string after the # is missing from my original URL!!

Comment: Like I said, that's impossible. The server never sees the hash part. Why do you need the hash part?

Comment: Well I am using wordpress if I do not use the hash part then I get a page not found error!!

Comment: @DebakantMohanty Then I suggest you use `mod_rewrite` for that.

Comment: Thanks Fred,I am not sure how to use a mod_rewrite in my wordpress .htaccess file, can you please send me a sample??

Answer (score 2):

Use `$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]`:

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

Comment: Well using "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]" I only get up to http://wp.raddyx.in/consultant-dietitians/staff-single/ but I want get the string after the # i.e. http://wp.raddyx.in/consultant-dietitians/staff-single/#Fiona%20Brown

Comment: @novo, `echo "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";` produces `http://localhost/test.php` for me. My PHP version must be magic :)

Comment: @Novocaine88 It is possible notation

Comment: @davidkonrad The browser doesn't actually send anything that comes after the hash(#) to the server because it is resolved within the browser.

Comment: My bad, I assumed the use of quotes within the array e.g. `['HTTP_HOST']` which wouldn't work. In my haste glazed over the fact you didn't do that, in which case this is fine.

Comment: @zavg - doesnt remember claiming that #fragments was included in REQUEST_URI

Comment: This solution will fail for `https://`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```